# How can i add icon to bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, glyphicons

I have this code

```
        <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

which looks like

[image]

I want to add icon like cog insteaqd of Text like this

[image]

I have tried this

`<button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></button>`

buts not working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a button, the icon needs to go inside the button as the button's contents, so instead of `<button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></button>`
it should be

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
</button>
```

Edit: to add the caret in Bootstrap, you use `<span class="caret"></span>`

So the end result to get a button with a cog and dropdown caret is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

When I paste that code into Bootstrap's homepage, I get this:
[image: cog button]

Comment: Check out this thread, if you are using bootstrap 4 (in which glyphicon font has been removed): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can use this code

Answer (score 0):

Just add this span tag

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

See this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/48w7zrez/1/)**