# Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?

Tags: bootstrap-4, glyphicons

We have a project that uses glyphicons intensively.
Bootstrap v4 drops the glyphicon font altogether.

Is there an equivalent for icons shipped with Bootstrap V4?

[image: Changelog]

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: You can still use [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/), they simply won't be shipped with bootstrap anymore. If you have [license](http://glyphicons.com/license/) issue, you could check [font awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/).

Comment: I believe you have to pay to use the font. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: There is a free license where you have to put a link to glyphicons (see GLYPHICON FREE section in my previous link). As I said in my previous comment, there are alternatives such as font awesome which are open source and free, but knowing which one is the best will clearly be opinion based...

Comment: That would be great, but the free package doesn't offer the font, only the PNG files. Apparently, only the PRO package includes _All icons as a web font_. While you are very helpful (thank you), the question is more about included components in Bootstrap, if you can confirm that no icons of any type are (or will be) included in the v4, you can generate an answer.

Comment: If you go to the provided link fontawesome.io, you will be requested a payment of $60 or $99 if you wait too much, so I believe, fontawesome is not longer free.

Comment: LineIcons is 100% free and you can get them there: https://lineicons.com/icons/

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can use both [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) and [Github Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/) as a free alternative for Glyphicons.

Bootstrap 4 also switched from Less to Sass, so you might integerate the font's Sass (SCSS) into you build process, to create a single CSS file for your projects.

Also see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/ to find out how to set up your tooling:

1. Download and install Node, which we use to manage our dependencies.
2. Navigate to the root `/bootstrap` directory and run `npm install` to install our local dependencies listed in package.json.
3. Install Ruby, install Bundler with `gem install bundler`, and finally run `bundle install`. This will install all Ruby dependencies, such as Jekyll and plugins.

**Font Awesome**

1. Download the files at https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/fa-4
2. Copy the `font-awesome/scss` folder into your /bootstrap folder
3. Open your SCSS `/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss` and write down the following SCSS code at the end of this file:

   `$fa-font-path: "../fonts";
   @import "../font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";`
4. Notice that you also have to copy the font file from `font-awesome/fonts` to `dist/fonts` or any other public folder set by `$fa-font-path` in the previous step
5. Run: `npm run dist` to recompile your code with Font-Awesome

**Github Octicons**

1. Download the files at https://github.com/github/octicons/
2. Copy the `octicons` folder into your `/bootstrap` folder
3. Open your SCSS `/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss` and write down the following SCSS code at the end of this file:

   `$fa-font-path: "../fonts";
   @import "../octicons/octicons/octicons.scss";`
4. Notice that you also have to copy the font file from `font-awesome/fonts` to `dist/fonts` or any other public folder set by `$fa-font-path` in the previous step
5. Run: `npm run dist` to recompile your code with Octicons

**Glyphicons**

On the Bootstrap website you can read:

> Includes over 250 glyphs in font format from the Glyphicon Halflings set. Glyphicons Halflings are normally not available for free, but their creator has made them available for Bootstrap free of cost. As a thank you, we only ask that you include a link back to Glyphicons whenever possible.

As I understand you can use these 250 glyphs free of cost restricted for Bootstrap but not limited to version 3 exclusive. So you can use them for Bootstrap 4 too.

1. Copy the fonts files from: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/fonts/bootstrap
2. Copy the https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss file into your `bootstrap/scss` folder
3. Open your scss /bootstrap/bootstrap.scss and write down the following SCSS code at the end of this file:

```
$bootstrap-sass-asset-helper: false;
$icon-font-name: 'glyphicons-halflings-regular';
$icon-font-svg-id: 'glyphicons_halflingsregular';
$icon-font-path: '../fonts/';
@import "glyphicons";
```

4. Run: `npm run dist` to recompile your code with Glyphicons

---

Notice that Bootstrap 4 requires the post CSS [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) for compiling. When you are using a static Sass compiler to compile your CSS you should have to run the Autoprefixer afterwards.

You can find out more about mixing with the Bootstrap 4 SCSS in [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/).

You can also use Bower to install the fonts above. Using Bower Font Awesome installs your files in `bower_components/components-font-awesome/` also notice that Github Octicons sets the `octicons/octicons/octicons-.scss` as the main file whilst you should use `octicons/octicons/sprockets-octicons.scss`.

All the above will compile all your CSS code including into a single file, which requires only one HTTP request. Alternatively you can also load the Font-Awesome font from CDN, which can be fast too in many situations. Both fonts on CDN also include the font files (using data-uri's, possible not supported for older browsers). So consider which solution best fits your situation depending on among others browsers to support.

For Font Awesome paste the following code into the `<head>` section of your site's HTML:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also try [Yeoman generator to scaffold out a front-end Bootstrap 4 Web app](https://github.com/bassjobsen/generator-bootstrap4) to test Bootstrap 4 with Font Awesome or Github Octicons.

Comment: This was very thorough and really helped clarify things for me and point me in the right direction of my choosing. Anyone know why BS4 decided not to ship with Glyphicon Halflings set? Just to slim down the package?

Comment: "Install Ruby"?! Why would I install a whole development framework only to use a font?! And how come you just mention it as a side note? It's superhuge since it changes semantics, build processes and dependencies of your whole project just to get to a font! It's inconceiveable to me how you can advise to do that.

Answer (score 302):

Migrating from Glyphicons to Font Awesome is quite easy.

Include a reference to Font Awesome (either locally, or use the CDN).

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then run a search and replace where you search for `glyphicon glyphicon-` and replace it with `fa fa-`, and also change the enclosing element from `<span` to `<i`. Most of the CSS class names are the same. Some have changed though, so you have to manually fix those.

Comment: Not all names is the same. This is map glyphicon icons to font-awesome: 
https://gist.github.com/blowsie/15f8fe303383e361958bd53ecb7294f9

Comment: `fa fa-` is depreciated.  Their website now says `fas fa-`, and this message: `The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.`

Comment: Version 5 isn't currently hosted on BootstrapCDN and having just `font-awesome.css` may not be enough. (e.g. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css` ) (4.7.0 still works and is recommended if you don't want to find that more names have changed.)

Comment: Unfortunately, icons are very different, for example, fire icons don't have anything in common and can't be used in a similar context.

Comment: The above comment (not part of the answer) about changing `fa` to `fas` appears to be incorrect. Even with 4.7.0, `fa` works fine and when I change it to `fas`, the icon becomes a square.

Answer (score 42):

The glyphicons.less file from Bootstrap 3 is available on GitHub.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/less/glyphicons.less

It needs these variables:

```
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
@icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular";
@icon-font-svg-id:        "glyphicons_halflingsregular";
```

Then you can convert the .less file to a .css file which you can use directly. You can do this online on [lesscss.org/less-preview/](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/). Here I've [done it for you](http://pastebin.com/7WFcBn0f), save it as glyphicons.css and include it in your HTML files.

```
<link href="/Content/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You also need the Glyphicon fonts which is in the Bootstrap 3 package, place them in a /fonts/ directory.

Now you can just keep on using Glyphicons with Bootstrap 4 as usual.

Comment: Fred, Thank You. Icons are displaying in Firefox and Chrome browsers. But in IE, Icons are displaying in 11.0.9600.19377 version but not in 11.0.9600.19356 version. How can i make the icons to display in IE version 11.0.9600.19356.
I have also checked the console and there are no errors in IE version 11.0.9600.19356

Comment: @Hemant, I don't know. Either way, this post is very old and from back when Glyphicons was at version 4. Today I would go for version 5.

Answer (score 25):

If needing only glyphicon classes
in CSS:

```css
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before{content:"\2a";}
.glyphicon-plus:before{content:"\2b";}
.glyphicon-euro:before{content:"\20ac";}
.glyphicon-minus:before{content:"\2212";}
.glyphicon-cloud:before{content:"\2601";}
.glyphicon-envelope:before{content:"\2709";}
.glyphicon-pencil:before{content:"\270f";}
.glyphicon-glass:before{content:"\e001";}
.glyphicon-music:before{content:"\e002";}
.glyphicon-search:before{content:"\e003";}
.glyphicon-heart:before{content:"\e005";}
.glyphicon-star:before{content:"\e006";}
.glyphicon-star-empty:before{content:"\e007";}
.glyphicon-user:before{content:"\e008";}
.glyphicon-film:before{content:"\e009";}
.glyphicon-th-large:before{content:"\e010";}
.glyphicon-th:before{content:"\e011";}
.glyphicon-th-list:before{content:"\e012";}
.glyphicon-ok:before{content:"\e013";}
.glyphicon-remove:before{content:"\e014";}
.glyphicon-zoom-in:before{content:"\e015";}
.glyphicon-zoom-out:before{content:"\e016";}
.glyphicon-off:before{content:"\e017";}
.glyphicon-signal:before{content:"\e018";}
.glyphicon-cog:before{content:"\e019";}
.glyphicon-trash:before{content:"\e020";}
.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021";}
.glyphicon-file:before{content:"\e022";}
.glyphicon-time:before{content:"\e023";}
.glyphicon-road:before{content:"\e024";}
.glyphicon-download-alt:before{content:"\e025";}
.glyphicon-download:before{content:"\e026";}
.glyphicon-upload:before{content:"\e027";}
.glyphicon-inbox:before{content:"\e028";}
.glyphicon-play-circle:before{content:"\e029";}
.glyphicon-repeat:before{content:"\e030";}
.glyphicon-refresh:before{content:"\e031";}
.glyphicon-list-alt:before{content:"\e032";}
.glyphicon-flag:before{content:"\e034";}
.glyphicon-headphones:before{content:"\e035";}
.glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036";}
.glyphicon-volume-down:before{content:"\e037";}
.glyphicon-volume-up:before{content:"\e038";}
.glyphicon-qrcode:before{content:"\e039";}
.glyphicon-barcode:before{content:"\e040";}
.glyphicon-tag:before{content:"\e041";}
.glyphicon-tags:before{content:"\e042";}
.glyphicon-book:before{content:"\e043";}
.glyphicon-print:before{content:"\e045";}
.glyphicon-font:before{content:"\e047";}
.glyphicon-bold:before{content:"\e048";}
.glyphicon-italic:before{content:"\e049";}
.glyphicon-text-height:before{content:"\e050";}
.glyphicon-text-width:before{content:"\e051";}
.glyphicon-align-left:before{content:"\e052";}
.glyphicon-align-center:before{content:"\e053";}
.glyphicon-align-right:before{content:"\e054";}
.glyphicon-align-justify:before{content:"\e055";}
.glyphicon-list:before{content:"\e056";}
.glyphicon-indent-left:before{content:"\e057";}
.glyphicon-indent-right:before{content:"\e058";}
.glyphicon-facetime-video:before{content:"\e059";}
.glyphicon-picture:before{content:"\e060";}
.glyphicon-map-marker:before{content:"\e062";}
.glyphicon-adjust:before{content:"\e063";}
.glyphicon-tint:before{content:"\e064";}
.glyphicon-edit:before{content:"\e065";}
.glyphicon-share:before{content:"\e066";}
.glyphicon-check:before{content:"\e067";}
.glyphicon-move:before{content:"\e068";}
.glyphicon-step-backward:before{content:"\e069";}
.glyphicon-fast-backward:before{content:"\e070";}
.glyphicon-backward:before{content:"\e071";}
.glyphicon-play:before{content:"\e072";}
.glyphicon-pause:before{content:"\e073";}
.glyphicon-stop:before{content:"\e074";}
.glyphicon-forward:before{content:"\e075";}
.glyphicon-fast-forward:before{content:"\e076";}
.glyphicon-step-forward:before{content:"\e077";}
.glyphicon-eject:before{content:"\e078";}
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{content:"\e079";}
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{content:"\e080";}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:before{content:"\e081";}
.glyphicon-minus-sign:before{content:"\e082";}
.glyphicon-remove-sign:before{content:"\e083";}
.glyphicon-ok-sign:before{content:"\e084";}
.glyphicon-question-sign:before{content:"\e085";}
.glyphicon-info-sign:before{content:"\e086";}
.glyphicon-screenshot:before{content:"\e087";}
.glyphicon-remove-circle:before{content:"\e088";}
.glyphicon-ok-circle:before{content:"\e089";}
.glyphicon-ban-circle:before{content:"\e090";}
.glyphicon-arrow-left:before{content:"\e091";}
.glyphicon-arrow-right:before{content:"\e092";}
.glyphicon-arrow-up:before{content:"\e093";}
.glyphicon-arrow-down:before{content:"\e094";}
.glyphicon-share-alt:before{content:"\e095";}
.glyphicon-resize-full:before{content:"\e096";}
.glyphicon-resize-small:before{content:"\e097";}
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before{content:"\e101";}
.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102";}
.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103";}
.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105";}
.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106";}
.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107";}
.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108";}
.glyphicon-random:before{content:"\e110";}
.glyphicon-comment:before{content:"\e111";}
.glyphicon-magnet:before{content:"\e112";}
.glyphicon-chevron-up:before{content:"\e113";}
.glyphicon-chevron-down:before{content:"\e114";}
.glyphicon-retweet:before{content:"\e115";}
.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before{content:"\e116";}
.glyphicon-folder-close:before{content:"\e117";}
.glyphicon-folder-open:before{content:"\e118";}
.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before{content:"\e119";}
.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before{content:"\e120";}
.glyphicon-hdd:before{content:"\e121";}
.glyphicon-bullhorn:before{content:"\e122";}
.glyphicon-certificate:before{content:"\e124";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{content:"\e125";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before{content:"\e126";}
.glyphicon-hand-right:before{content:"\e127";}
.glyphicon-hand-left:before{content:"\e128";}
.glyphicon-hand-up:before{content:"\e129";}
.glyphicon-hand-down:before{content:"\e130";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before{content:"\e131";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before{content:"\e132";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before{content:"\e133";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before{content:"\e134";}
.glyphicon-globe:before{content:"\e135";}
.glyphicon-tasks:before{content:"\e137";}
.glyphicon-filter:before{content:"\e138";}
.glyphicon-fullscreen:before{content:"\e140";}
.glyphicon-dashboard:before{content:"\e141";}
.glyphicon-heart-empty:before{content:"\e143";}
.glyphicon-link:before{content:"\e144";}
.glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145";}
.glyphicon-usd:before{content:"\e148";}
.glyphicon-gbp:before{content:"\e149";}
.glyphicon-sort:before{content:"\e150";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before{content:"\e151";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before{content:"\e152";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before{content:"\e153";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before{content:"\e154";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before{content:"\e155";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before{content:"\e156";}
.glyphicon-unchecked:before{content:"\e157";}
.glyphicon-expand:before{content:"\e158";}
.glyphicon-collapse-down:before{content:"\e159";}
.glyphicon-collapse-up:before{content:"\e160";}
.glyphicon-log-in:before{content:"\e161";}
.glyphicon-flash:before{content:"\e162";}
.glyphicon-log-out:before{content:"\e163";}
.glyphicon-new-window:before{content:"\e164";}
.glyphicon-record:before{content:"\e165";}
.glyphicon-save:before{content:"\e166";}
.glyphicon-open:before{content:"\e167";}
.glyphicon-saved:before{content:"\e168";}
.glyphicon-import:before{content:"\e169";}
.glyphicon-export:before{content:"\e170";}
.glyphicon-send:before{content:"\e171";}
.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before{content:"\e172";}
.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before{content:"\e173";}
.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before{content:"\e174";}
.glyphicon-floppy-save:before{content:"\e175";}
.glyphicon-floppy-open:before{content:"\e176";}
.glyphicon-credit-card:before{content:"\e177";}
.glyphicon-transfer:before{content:"\e178";}
.glyphicon-cutlery:before{content:"\e179";}
.glyphicon-header:before{content:"\e180";}
.glyphicon-compressed:before{content:"\e181";}
.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182";}
.glyphicon-phone-alt:before{content:"\e183";}
.glyphicon-tower:before{content:"\e184";}
.glyphicon-stats:before{content:"\e185";}
.glyphicon-sd-video:before{content:"\e186";}
.glyphicon-hd-video:before{content:"\e187";}
.glyphicon-subtitles:before{content:"\e188";}
.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before{content:"\e189";}
.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before{content:"\e190";}
.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before{content:"\e191";}
.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before{content:"\e192";}
.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before{content:"\e193";}
.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before{content:"\e194";}
.glyphicon-registration-mark:before{content:"\e195";}
.glyphicon-cloud-download:before{content:"\e197";}
.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before{content:"\e198";}
.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before{content:"\e199";}
.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before{content:"\e200";}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before{content:"\1f4bc";}
.glyphicon-calendar:before{content:"\1f4c5";}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before{content:"\1f4cc";}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before{content:"\1f4ce";}
.glyphicon-camera:before{content:"\1f4f7";}
.glyphicon-lock:before{content:"\1f512";}
.glyphicon-bell:before{content:"\1f514";}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before{content:"\1f516";}
.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\1f525";}
.glyphicon-wrench:before{content:"\1f527";}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to

https://github.com/Darkseal/bootstrap4-glyphicons

download and include in your code

```
<link href="bootstrap4-glyphicons/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not shipped with bootstrap 4 yet, but now Bootstrap team is developing their icon library.

https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

https://github.com/twbs/icons

Answer (score 3):

For people who are looking for one-liner solutions, you can import Bootstrap Glyphicons only:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
```

Comment: 2 things I remember: font change and bootstrap datepicker (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) looses its nice format

Answer (score 2):

Overview:

I am using bootstrap 4 without glyphicons.  I found a problem with bootstrap treeview that depends upon glyphicons.  I am using treeview as is, and I am using scss @extend to translate the icon class styles to font awesome class styles.  I think this is quite slick (if you ask me)!

Details:

I used scss @extend to handle it for me.

I previously decided to use font-awesome for no better reason than I have used it in the past.

When I went to try bootstrap treeview, I found that the icons were missing, because I didn't have glyphicons installed.

I decided to use the scss @extend feature, to have the glyphicon classes use the font-awesome classes as so:

```
.treeview {
  .glyphicon {
    @extend .fa;
  }
  .glyphicon-minus {
    @extend .fa-minus;
  }
  .glyphicon-plus {
    @extend .fa-plus;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel 5.6, it comes with Bootstrap 4. All you need to is:

```
npm install and npm install open-iconic --save
```

At `/resources/assets/sass/app.scss` change the line of of Google font import on line 2 to

```
@import '~open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap';
```

All you need to do now is

```
npm run watch
```

and include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
```

on top of master blade file and `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` before closing body tag. You will get Bootstrap 4 and icon.

Usage is `<span class="oi oi-cog"></span>`

Refer here for icon details: [Open Iconic: Recommended by Bootstrap 4](https://useiconic.com/open/)

If on other project than Laravel, you can just do import `@import 'node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap-min.css';` in your style file.

Hope this helps. Happy trying.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 files do not come with the glyphicon support. But you can simply open up your bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css and paste this code which I came across here.

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before{content:"\2a";}
.glyphicon-plus:before{content:"\2b";}
.glyphicon-euro:before{content:"\20ac";}
.glyphicon-minus:before{content:"\2212";}
.glyphicon-cloud:before{content:"\2601";}
.glyphicon-envelope:before{content:"\2709";}
.glyphicon-pencil:before{content:"\270f";}
.glyphicon-glass:before{content:"\e001";}
.glyphicon-music:before{content:"\e002";}
.glyphicon-search:before{content:"\e003";}
.glyphicon-heart:before{content:"\e005";}
.glyphicon-star:before{content:"\e006";}
.glyphicon-star-empty:before{content:"\e007";}
.glyphicon-user:before{content:"\e008";}
.glyphicon-film:before{content:"\e009";}
.glyphicon-th-large:before{content:"\e010";}
.glyphicon-th:before{content:"\e011";}
.glyphicon-th-list:before{content:"\e012";}
.glyphicon-ok:before{content:"\e013";}
.glyphicon-remove:before{content:"\e014";}
.glyphicon-zoom-in:before{content:"\e015";}
.glyphicon-zoom-out:before{content:"\e016";}
.glyphicon-off:before{content:"\e017";}
.glyphicon-signal:before{content:"\e018";}
.glyphicon-cog:before{content:"\e019";}
.glyphicon-trash:before{content:"\e020";}
.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021";}
.glyphicon-file:before{content:"\e022";}
.glyphicon-time:before{content:"\e023";}
.glyphicon-road:before{content:"\e024";}
.glyphicon-download-alt:before{content:"\e025";}
.glyphicon-download:before{content:"\e026";}
.glyphicon-upload:before{content:"\e027";}
.glyphicon-inbox:before{content:"\e028";}
.glyphicon-play-circle:before{content:"\e029";}
.glyphicon-repeat:before{content:"\e030";}
.glyphicon-refresh:before{content:"\e031";}
.glyphicon-list-alt:before{content:"\e032";}
.glyphicon-flag:before{content:"\e034";}
.glyphicon-headphones:before{content:"\e035";}
.glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036";}
.glyphicon-volume-down:before{content:"\e037";}
.glyphicon-volume-up:before{content:"\e038";}
.glyphicon-qrcode:before{content:"\e039";}
.glyphicon-barcode:before{content:"\e040";}
.glyphicon-tag:before{content:"\e041";}
.glyphicon-tags:before{content:"\e042";}
.glyphicon-book:before{content:"\e043";}
.glyphicon-print:before{content:"\e045";}
.glyphicon-font:before{content:"\e047";}
.glyphicon-bold:before{content:"\e048";}
.glyphicon-italic:before{content:"\e049";}
.glyphicon-text-height:before{content:"\e050";}
.glyphicon-text-width:before{content:"\e051";}
.glyphicon-align-left:before{content:"\e052";}
.glyphicon-align-center:before{content:"\e053";}
.glyphicon-align-right:before{content:"\e054";}
.glyphicon-align-justify:before{content:"\e055";}
.glyphicon-list:before{content:"\e056";}
.glyphicon-indent-left:before{content:"\e057";}
.glyphicon-indent-right:before{content:"\e058";}
.glyphicon-facetime-video:before{content:"\e059";}
.glyphicon-picture:before{content:"\e060";}
.glyphicon-map-marker:before{content:"\e062";}
.glyphicon-adjust:before{content:"\e063";}
.glyphicon-tint:before{content:"\e064";}
.glyphicon-edit:before{content:"\e065";}
.glyphicon-share:before{content:"\e066";}
.glyphicon-check:before{content:"\e067";}
.glyphicon-move:before{content:"\e068";}
.glyphicon-step-backward:before{content:"\e069";}
.glyphicon-fast-backward:before{content:"\e070";}
.glyphicon-backward:before{content:"\e071";}
.glyphicon-play:before{content:"\e072";}
.glyphicon-pause:before{content:"\e073";}
.glyphicon-stop:before{content:"\e074";}
.glyphicon-forward:before{content:"\e075";}
.glyphicon-fast-forward:before{content:"\e076";}
.glyphicon-step-forward:before{content:"\e077";}
.glyphicon-eject:before{content:"\e078";}
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{content:"\e079";}
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{content:"\e080";}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:before{content:"\e081";}
.glyphicon-minus-sign:before{content:"\e082";}
.glyphicon-remove-sign:before{content:"\e083";}
.glyphicon-ok-sign:before{content:"\e084";}
.glyphicon-question-sign:before{content:"\e085";}
.glyphicon-info-sign:before{content:"\e086";}
.glyphicon-screenshot:before{content:"\e087";}
.glyphicon-remove-circle:before{content:"\e088";}
.glyphicon-ok-circle:before{content:"\e089";}
.glyphicon-ban-circle:before{content:"\e090";}
.glyphicon-arrow-left:before{content:"\e091";}
.glyphicon-arrow-right:before{content:"\e092";}
.glyphicon-arrow-up:before{content:"\e093";}
.glyphicon-arrow-down:before{content:"\e094";}
.glyphicon-share-alt:before{content:"\e095";}
.glyphicon-resize-full:before{content:"\e096";}
.glyphicon-resize-small:before{content:"\e097";}
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before{content:"\e101";}
.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102";}
.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103";}
.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105";}
.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106";}
.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107";}
.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108";}
.glyphicon-random:before{content:"\e110";}
.glyphicon-comment:before{content:"\e111";}
.glyphicon-magnet:before{content:"\e112";}
.glyphicon-chevron-up:before{content:"\e113";}
.glyphicon-chevron-down:before{content:"\e114";}
.glyphicon-retweet:before{content:"\e115";}
.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before{content:"\e116";}
.glyphicon-folder-close:before{content:"\e117";}
.glyphicon-folder-open:before{content:"\e118";}
.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before{content:"\e119";}
.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before{content:"\e120";}
.glyphicon-hdd:before{content:"\e121";}
.glyphicon-bullhorn:before{content:"\e122";}
.glyphicon-certificate:before{content:"\e124";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{content:"\e125";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before{content:"\e126";}
.glyphicon-hand-right:before{content:"\e127";}
.glyphicon-hand-left:before{content:"\e128";}
.glyphicon-hand-up:before{content:"\e129";}
.glyphicon-hand-down:before{content:"\e130";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before{content:"\e131";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before{content:"\e132";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before{content:"\e133";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before{content:"\e134";}
.glyphicon-globe:before{content:"\e135";}
.glyphicon-tasks:before{content:"\e137";}
.glyphicon-filter:before{content:"\e138";}
.glyphicon-fullscreen:before{content:"\e140";}
.glyphicon-dashboard:before{content:"\e141";}
.glyphicon-heart-empty:before{content:"\e143";}
.glyphicon-link:before{content:"\e144";}
.glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145";}
.glyphicon-usd:before{content:"\e148";}
.glyphicon-gbp:before{content:"\e149";}
.glyphicon-sort:before{content:"\e150";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before{content:"\e151";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before{content:"\e152";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before{content:"\e153";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before{content:"\e154";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before{content:"\e155";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before{content:"\e156";}
.glyphicon-unchecked:before{content:"\e157";}
.glyphicon-expand:before{content:"\e158";}
.glyphicon-collapse-down:before{content:"\e159";}
.glyphicon-collapse-up:before{content:"\e160";}
.glyphicon-log-in:before{content:"\e161";}
.glyphicon-flash:before{content:"\e162";}
.glyphicon-log-out:before{content:"\e163";}
.glyphicon-new-window:before{content:"\e164";}
.glyphicon-record:before{content:"\e165";}
.glyphicon-save:before{content:"\e166";}
.glyphicon-open:before{content:"\e167";}
.glyphicon-saved:before{content:"\e168";}
.glyphicon-import:before{content:"\e169";}
.glyphicon-export:before{content:"\e170";}
.glyphicon-send:before{content:"\e171";}
.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before{content:"\e172";}
.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before{content:"\e173";}
.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before{content:"\e174";}
.glyphicon-floppy-save:before{content:"\e175";}
.glyphicon-floppy-open:before{content:"\e176";}
.glyphicon-credit-card:before{content:"\e177";}
.glyphicon-transfer:before{content:"\e178";}
.glyphicon-cutlery:before{content:"\e179";}
.glyphicon-header:before{content:"\e180";}
.glyphicon-compressed:before{content:"\e181";}
.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182";}
.glyphicon-phone-alt:before{content:"\e183";}
.glyphicon-tower:before{content:"\e184";}
.glyphicon-stats:before{content:"\e185";}
.glyphicon-sd-video:before{content:"\e186";}
.glyphicon-hd-video:before{content:"\e187";}
.glyphicon-subtitles:before{content:"\e188";}
.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before{content:"\e189";}
.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before{content:"\e190";}
.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before{content:"\e191";}
.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before{content:"\e192";}
.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before{content:"\e193";}
.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before{content:"\e194";}
.glyphicon-registration-mark:before{content:"\e195";}
.glyphicon-cloud-download:before{content:"\e197";}
.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before{content:"\e198";}
.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before{content:"\e199";}
.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before{content:"\e200";}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before{content:"\1f4bc";}
.glyphicon-calendar:before{content:"\1f4c5";}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before{content:"\1f4cc";}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before{content:"\1f4ce";}
.glyphicon-camera:before{content:"\1f4f7";}
.glyphicon-lock:before{content:"\1f512";}
.glyphicon-bell:before{content:"\1f514";}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before{content:"\1f516";}
.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\1f525";}
.glyphicon-wrench:before{content:"\1f527";}
```