# Does Bootstrap 4 alpha support glyphicon?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've tried to include glyph-icon in Bootstrap v4 alpha template. But any icon didn't show. That's why I want to know that does v4 support glyph-icon or doesn't?

Comment: Please include some code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Bootstrap 4 Migrating Guide:](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)

> Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
>
> - the upstream version of [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)
> - Octicons
> - Font Awesome

Comment: What does 'the upstream version' mean? Is that their own language or is that a thing?

Comment: It's the version developed and maintained by the original author. For more on this term, read this article on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development)).