# background color on search glyphicon

Tags: html, css, search, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get my the background color on my search glyph to take up the full box. Ideally, it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aS2i.jpg).

However, it currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt93Y.jpg).

I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's my html (I'm using Bootstrap).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="custom-search-input">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search by user name, member types, genres..." />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited to add my CSS:

```
#custom-search-input{
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 75%;
}

#custom-search-input input{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.input-group-btn{
    background: #E44424;
}

#custom-search-input button{
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    background: #E44424;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#custom-search-input button:hover{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#custom-search-input .glyphicon-search{
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You'd need to apply the bg color to `.input-group-btn` with a separate class.

Comment: Please include your CSS, thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PJwqOq

Comment: #custom-search-input{
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 75%;
}

#custom-search-input input{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#custom-search-input button{
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    background: #E44424;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#custom-search-input button:hover{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have padding in

```
    #custom-search-input{ 
       padding: 3px; 
    }
```

That's the reason.
You should instead have it on

```
    .form-control{
    padding: 3px; 
    }
```

if you need padding on input

[Here's Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x5Jr1BfxwpAb41gtA0S8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, Mickey. I inputted your code but it still looks wonky. There's a sliver of white around the background color still on all side.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I updated the original post with a new image. Changed the colors, but you can still see the hint of white behind the blue of the looking glass box.

Comment: The culprit is "border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;". Remove it.

Comment: SO much better. Thank you!