# A Little Bootstrap Obscurity... Maybe?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

The Glyphicon doesn't display according to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/  It could be that I've overlooked something obvious.

Here's the code:

```
<section id="feature">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-5">
            <h3>Gamma Features</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 1</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 2</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 3</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img class="big-logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Yes, you're right. I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta at 'css/bootstrap.css' and 'js/bootstrap.js'

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Gamma: Photo-Sharing App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand green-text" href="#">Gamma</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <h1>Capture <span class="green-text">Life</span></h1>
            <p>A fun and easy way to capture & share the moments you live for</p>
            <a href="#"><img src="./img/icon_app_store.png" alt="apple store" class="app-btn"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="./img/icon_google_play.png" alt="google play" class="app-btn"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="showCase-img" src="./img/site_phone.png" alt="phone">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section id="middle">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="./img/demo1.jpg" alt="two phones" class="demo-1">
              <h2>Lorem</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark" role="button">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="./img/demo2.jpg" alt="three phones" class="demo-2">
              <h2>Lorem</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark" role="button">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="./img/demo3.jpg" alt="artwork" class="demo-3">
              <h2>Lorem</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark" role="button">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="feature">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
          <div class="col-5">
            <h3>Gamma Features</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 1</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 2</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 3</li>
              <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Feature 4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <img class="big-logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #FFF;
  padding-top: 4rem; }

.green-text {
  color: #1CAA98 !important; }

.jumbotron {
  background: url(../img/site_showcase_bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: none; }
  .jumbotron img.app-btn {
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline; }
  .jumbotron h1 {
    margin-top: 60px; }
  .jumbotron p {
    margin-bottom: 40px; }
  .jumbotron img.showCase-img {
    max-width: 100%; }

section#middle {
  padding: 10px 0 40px 0; }
  section#middle img.demo-1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; }
  section#middle img.demo-2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; }
  section#middle img.demo-3 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; }

section#feature {
  background: #1CAA98;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: auto; }
  section#feature ul li {
    font-size: 22px;
    list-style: none; }
  section#feature .big-logo {
    width: 100%; }
```

I also found additional info at: 'https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components'.  It looks like this signals that the "Glyphicons" were dropped!?? Not sure. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: please  explain in detail with css html and other detail

Comment: Looks like you're using Bootstrap 4, not 3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, yes, the "Glyphicons" were dropped according to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components .  I replaced them with "Font Awesome" at: http://fontawesome.io --one of their suggested alternatives.  Problem solved.