# Why glyph icons were taken off in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

In bootstrap 3 we have font, using that we can able to use glyph icons but in bootstrap 4 there were no font and glyph icons can't be used. I want to know is  why they took glyph icon and the replacement for the glyph icon in bootstrap 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [question](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18749) about this on the Bootstrap repo. Quote:

> While icon fonts in general do have some issues, I don't recall that
>   being the primary consideration for dropping them. The more pressing
>   concern was that (A) some folks don't need/want icons (B) many folks
>   were using other icon fonts (such as Font Awesome); for folks in these
>   circumstances, Bootstrap including its own icon font led to
>   unnecessary bloat. Plus, dedicated icon font projects could do a
>   better job than us.

I'd recommend using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) for icons, as:

- it has almost 700 icons (v 4.7.0)
- it has good docs
- it is actively developed