# Glyphicon not working in bootstrap version 4.1 and later

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I tried to show a **search icon** in form but the only button is shown without the glyphs.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

**RESULT**
[image]

I use bootstrap version 4.1. I got the glyphicon code [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) and form [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @mlegg Bootstrap version 4.1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Glyphicons are dropped from Bootstrap V4 and later.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here, *[Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io)* is used. Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33768443/7678788) for more alternatives to Glyphicons and Font Awesome

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 4 dropped the Glyphicons icon font.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components

Comment: Describe the reason and additionally provide external link not as primary.

Comment: on the getbootstrap link I provided it says "Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:

    the upstream version of Glyphicons
    Octicons
    Font Awesome
    See the Extend page for a list of alternatives"

Comment: You should say those in answer and for details you can refer the audience to that page.

Comment: What do I do to get Glyphicons in bootstrap 5.3? @mlegg