# How to fix Bootstrap-3 and Bootstrap-4 difference problems?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm learning Angular with a little-bit old tutorial because instructor uses bootstrap 3.3.7 and at the present time I've downloaded bootstrap 4.4.1 version with which I cannot follow instructor and implement some futures (glyphicons).

Can I install the old version of bootstrap in particular project- to follow the instructor to the end of course?
Or can I somehow with other way fix this problem - I mean: fix the differences in bootstrap versions?

Sorry for bad English and many thanks in advance!

Comment: you can add glyphicons library to BS4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no breaking change from bootstrap 3 to 4 so there shouldn't be any difference but in the scope of doing a tutorial I would switch to bootstrap 3 to make sure I have exactly the same result as the author.

It limits the amount of uncertainty and will make for a better learning experience : when something goes wrong you can focus on your code instead of wondering if it's because of the bootstrap version you're using.

Depending on your package manager :

**with npm**

```sh
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save --save-exact
```

**with yarn**

```sh
yarn add bootstrap@3.3.7
```

This will replace your current bootstrap version

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I've followed your advice and ordered to install 3.3.7 version but have'd  got  3.4.1 (in package.json). I think there must not be too big differences.

Comment: Oh that's my bad. Being a yarn user I'm not too familiar with npm's syntax. The correct syntax to install a specific version seems to be `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save --save-exact` I updated my answer accordingly, but you're right, 3.4.1 should be fine for the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of boostrap-3. There are some notable changes. Therefore,  I think you should include all of boostrap-3 resources
in your project and follow you instructor. Otherwise, you may use a lot of time configuring the differences. Later on, you can easily migrate. This links may help you.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/
- https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

If you use bootstap-3, you need to remove bootstrap-4 from your `html` file.

In case, you stick to bootstrap-4. You can use icons like font-aswesome, featericon, and bootsrap-4 icons, because bootstrap-4 has dropped Glyphicons. This guides help you how to use icons.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/
- [Glyphicon not working in bootstrap version 4.1 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905458/glyphicon-not-working-in-bootstrap-version-4-1-and-later)
- [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)
- https://github.com/feathericons/feather#feather

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
Links seems to be very usefully to me!
As I've understood, at the present time I have to just order older version.