# Can we use glyphicons in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

I have been using glyphicons with bootstrap 3 and now when I update the cdn to bootstrap 4, they don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, Bootstrap dropped support of them. however, you can always add it to your website manually.

There are files or CDN's for it so you should not have any problems adding it to your website.

There are also loads of alternatives like Material Icons by Google or FA.

[Download Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)

Comment: As discussed on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components  you can use https://glyphicons.com/

Answer (score 1):

glyphicons have been dropped support from bootstrap 4 and they worked with bootstrap 3. You can use use font-awesome instead. Migrating to font-awesome is easier:
you can include the cdn

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or download it from https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/ and replace glyphicon glyphicon- with fa fa- using any text editor.