# I am trying to add home glyphicon with bootstrap class in my navigationbar. But it is not showing in the output page. any fixes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add home icon using bootstrap glyphicon. but it is not showing in the output. help me with it?

I already tried to increse font size or changing font color but none of them worked.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The support for glyphicons is dropped in bootstrap 4. 
But still you can include it manually by

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly a duplicate of [Can we use glyphicons in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970966/can-we-use-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-4).

To summarize, support for Bootstrap 4 has been dropped.

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/timd3v/pen/PoYBjXM?editors=1000)

**Changes**

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Hope this helped.