# glyphicon not showing inside a button

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following button:

```
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" (click)="myFuncion()"></button>
```

After upgrade my bootstrap library from 3 to 4.2.1 the icon stop showing.

I was tried to insert the `glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal` classes into `span` or `i` but it's not looks like before

Answer (score 2):

as Bootstrap 4+ have to use the fontawesome icons instead of glyphicons 
please check the below stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfjyrc

```
<P>Boot strap 4+ using font awesome</P>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Primary</button>

<p>Bootstrap 4+ using glyphicon</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
  </button>
```

Please check this url for more details 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="myFuncion()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
</button>
```

**Update:** 
I've just found that glyphicon were removed from BT4, so you should add it manually. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612690/5955138) out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying what you suggest but it's not showing as expected, It's show like empty button without the glyphicon

Comment: Please add screenshot, or create stackblitz repo.