# Bootstrap not working with webpack fails to find fonts

Tags: javascript, webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-4

Im trying to bundle my project using webpack 4.

structure for bootstrap:

```
public
    css
    images
    js
    vendor
        bootstrap\dist
            css
            fonts
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2  
            js
```

webpack is unable to locate "fonts" and throws error while building
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error as text instead of an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as i was using bootstrap 4 and  Bootstrap v4 drops the glyphicon font altogether.so, the error occurs instead downgrading with version 3 and below works.
[image]

Font Awesome can be used alternative to glyphicons on bootstarp 4.
[Bootstrap 4 - Glyphicons migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration)